# What's the right way to convert from a IndexedSeq[Future[Foo]] to a Future[IndexedSeq[Foo]]?

Tags: scala

Per the title, given a `IndexedSeq[Future[Foo]]`, I would like to produce a future that completes when all futures of the original `IndexedSeq` have completed. What's the best way to do this? If there is something like `Future.sequence` for lists, is there a nice way to chain the call?

Consider two cases:

```
bar.createFuture(blah)     // Future[A]
  .flatMap(f1)             // f1: A -> Future[B]
  .flatMap(f2)             // f2: B -> Future[C]
  .map(f3)                 // f3: C -> IndexedSeq[Future[D]],
                           //   but would like to call flatMap(f3...???)

bar.createIndexedSeq(blah) // IndexedSeq[A]
  .map(f1)                 // f1: A -> B
  .map(f2)                 // f2: B -> C
  .map(f3)                 // f3: C -> Future[D]
  .???                     // convert IndexedSeq[Future[D]]
                           //   into Future[IndexedSeq[D]]
  .map(f4)                 // f4: IndexedSeq[D] -> E
```

Comment: This won't win a price for Reactive Beauty, but what I've often done is create a CountDownLatch with a count for each future.  When each future completes (good or bad) it decrements the count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for an unknown number of futures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395134/wait-for-an-unknown-number-of-futures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future.sequence` will convert from a `IndexedSeq[Future[Foo]]` to a `Future[IndexedSeq[Foo]]`, in fact it will convert any collection of futures into a future holding a collection of the same type.

Your first use case can be written like:

```
for {
  x <- bar.createFuture(blah)
  y <- f1(x)
  z <- f2(y)
  w <- Future.sequence(f3(z))
} yield w
```

Your second can be written like:

```
Future.sequence(bar.createIndexedSeq(blah) map f1 map f2 map f3) map f4
```

Or with `Future.traverse`:

```
Future.traverse(bar.createIndexedSeq(blah) map f1 map f2)(f3) map f4
```

Comment: Thanks, is there not some sort of collector that will do this job for the second example above? I was trying to keep all of the operations in a logical order. I'm actually having problems with the implicit parameters supplied to Future.sequence (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796942/execute-future-sequence-with-custom-executioncontext).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a collector, but logical order is preserved in the example, except for the `Future.traverse` being over on the side. If this bothers you, you can rewrite it with intermediate results in `val`s and break it into as many lines as you want.