# Execute Future.sequence with custom ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, reactive-programming

I'm trying to create a `Future[List[Int]]` from a `List[Future[Int]]` using a specified `ExecutionContext`. However, I'm getting errors about a second implicit parameter cbf of type `CanBuildFrom`. I don't fully understand the purpose of the `CanBuildFrom` parameter, and I'm getting errors when I try to omit it that look like the following:

```
- not enough arguments for method sequence: (implicit cbf:       scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]],Int,List[Int]]
```

Can someone explain this, and suggest a solution? Here is my current test code, which suffers the above compilation error:

```
val my: List[Future[Int]] = Future.successful(1) :: Future.successful(2) :: Future.successful(3) :: Nil
val zz: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(my)(ec)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Future.sequence` needs a `CanBuildFrom` to build the collection inside the `Future` it returns. Many other methods in the standard library require a `CanBuildFrom`, for example most `map` methods in the collections API.

`Future.sequence`'s implicit parameter list consists of two parameters, and both must be present in any invocation. To specify one explicitly and the other implicitly, use `implicitly`. For example:

```
val zz: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(my)(implicitly, ec)
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use `implicitly`, but I learned something new today. Slick!

Comment: What is a CanBuildFrom though? How could I create one non-implicitly?

Comment: @jonderry `CanBuildFrom` is a factory for builders for whatever collection is appropriate to return. You can manually create one by creating a class that implements the `CanBuildFrom` trait.