# How can you compose dependent futures in Scala so that all but one run in parallel?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future, flatmap

For example you can do:

```
Future(/* A */).flatMap(_ => Future(/* B */).flatMap(_ => Future(/* C */)))
```

Here B depends on A to complete, is there a clean way to compose the futures so that C depends on both A and B to complete and A and B can run in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Future.sequence](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html) method that allows you reduce a sequence of `Future`s into a single `Future`. Here is a simple example:

```
def createFuture(name: String, sleep: Int): Future[(String, Int)] = {
  Future({
    println(s"Starting $name with sleep $sleep")
    Thread.sleep(sleep)
    println(s"After $name")
    (name, sleep)
  })
}

val rnd = new Random()
val fa = createFuture("A", rnd.nextInt(1000) + 500)
val fb = createFuture("B", rnd.nextInt(1000) + 500)
val ff = Future.sequence(List(fa, fb)).flatMap(l => createFuture("C" + l.map(_._2).sum, 100))
Await.result(ff, Duration.Inf)
```

Output for one of runs is:

> Starting B with sleep 1287 
>   Starting A with sleep 550  
>   After A 
>   After B 
>   Starting C1837 with sleep 100 
>   After C1837

If you also want to have "fast failure", you may consider a more complicated answers from [How to wait for several Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256279/how-to-wait-for-several-futures)

Answer (score 0):

`for yield` is clean way to do this and it's equal to `flatMap`, like:

```
val futureA = Future {
  // do something
}
val futureB = Future {
  // do something
}
for {
_ <- futureA
_ <- futureB
} yield Future {
  /* C */
}
```

Initial `futureA` and `futureB` before `for comprehensive`, they will run in parallel.

Comment: I need A and B to run in parallel though, this will run them sequentially

Comment: @goodOldFashioned This will only run them sequentially if you start them in the `for` comprehension.  If `futureA` and `futureB` are something like `Future[_]` and not `() => Future[_]` then this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

`Future(A).zipWith(Future(B))((_,_) => C)`