# Java - Should I use a AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am stuck with the situation where :

A new object is instantiated with an array of size `n` of unset references (`null`).

A build step should assign each index a reference exactly once and then returns the full-filled array.

The complexity is that the array is feeded in parallel by multiple threads.

I don't care with the atomicity of the set operation because two threads can't access the same index, however, I would like to be sure that the thread that returns the filled array "sees" every index filled.

```
private final String[] arr = new String[n];

private void parallelFeed() {...} // Multi-threaded

public void build() {
    parallelFeed(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Should I use an `AtomicReferenceArray` ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `parallelFeed`, start your feeder threads.  Your feeder threads are assumed to not overlap, and to have each their own range so that together they fully fill the array.  Then in `parallelFeed`, `join` the threads.  `parallelFeed` will wait for the other theads to complete.  Assuming no thread fails to do its job, `parallelFeed` "sees" that all indexes have been filled.

**NOTE**

Since you mention "Scala Futures" in your comment, take a look at 
 [How to wait for several futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256279/how-to-wait-for-several-futures) for more discussion on ways to "join" up multiple futures where errors might occur.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, not sure of how I should `join` threads. I am currently using the Scala's Future API  which is quite similar to Java's one.
I am waiting for futures to complete with a `Await.ready(Futures.sequence(futures), 1.hour)`, do you know if this operation joins the threads ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Assuming `futures` is just a list of `Future`s, yes, that should work (after fixing the typo, `Futures.sequence` s/b `Future.sequence` )

Answer (score 1):

If each thread only handles its own set of indexes then all you need to do is `join` on all the threads from the 'thread that returns the filled array' in order to wait until they all are done running. No, need for `AtomicReferenceArray`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to guarantee visibility, what you're essentially after is the [`volatile`](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) keyword. Unfortunately, `volatile` [does not work well with arrays](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/volatile_arrays.shtml), and you'd need to work around it somewhat. It's possible, as that link explains, but I wouldn't recommend it.

I would implement this as a collection of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s. Each task would be a `Future<String[]>` and the "main" thread would compile all the results into the final array. See below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Test
{
    private String[] arr = new String[2];

    public Test() throws Exception // You may want to handle the exceptions more
    {                              // gracefully than this
        final int NUM_THREADS = 10;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

        // Start the tasks
        List<Future<String[]>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        tasks.add(
            executor.submit(() -> partOne())
        );
        tasks.add(
            executor.submit(() -> partTwo())
        );

        // Compile result
        for (Future<String[]> task : tasks)
        {
            final String[] result = task.get(); // This will wait if necessary
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i)
            {
                if (result[i] != null) arr[i] = result[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static String[] partOne()
    {
        String[] arr = new String[2];
        arr[0] = "Hello";
        return arr;
    }

    private static String[] partTwo()
    {
        String[] arr = new String[2];
        arr[1] = "World";
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make writing threads write to a `volatile` field once they done their part of filling an array. Then read that `volatile` field before right before `return arr`. Since writing / reading of `volatile` field establishes `happens-before`, you'll ensure visibility of data in array.

Above assumes no additional sync between threads necessary -- i.e., they can't write to same index, or smth like that.

Sample code:

```
public class WriteReadSyncArray<E> {

    private final E[] store;
    private volatile boolean sync;

    public WriteReadSyncArray(int size) {
        this.store = (E[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public void write(int index, E el) {
        store[index] = el;
        sync = true;
    }

    public E[] syncAndReadArray() {
        boolean localSync = sync; // establishes happens-before with all previous writes
        return store;
    }
}
```

Comment: Volatile [doesn't work properly when assigning to indexes of an array](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/volatile_arrays.shtml).

Comment: @Michael linked resources describes not what I proposing.

Comment: Then what were you proposing?

Comment: I just realized that OP code implies `parallelFeed` should return only when all writers finished, eg, by using `join`. If this is a case, no need to use `volatile` — join establishes happens-before as well.